# Why is my click event not firing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a form with a button. When the button is clicked I want to run a jQuery code. I have not been able to get it to work and am getting really frustrated. First I thought my selector was not right. So, I tried to test it by changing the click event to hover event. Hover event WORKED. Exactly the same button, exactly the same jQuery code. The only difference is that I changed it to Hover. Why is it not working on click? Any ideas?
Code is here

this doesnt fire:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#marketFloorID .sellButton").click(function(){
alert('works');
})
})
```

this does fire:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#marketFloorID .sellButton").hover(function(){
alert('works');
}),
function(){
//code;    
})
})
```

Comment: Because you did something wrong. That's all I can say with the information you have given. Maybe have a look at this tutorial: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/.

Comment: ideas would flow in after you show us your code..

Comment: where is this rogue code of yours?

Comment: what about some code?

Comment: @user2395238 Could you please provide your not working code?

Comment: my point is, it is the same code, the same selector. It fires perfectly when i change it to hover. but it doesn't when it's a click

Comment: can you put your html too ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

using element's id:

```
    $(function(){
        $('#yourID').on('click',function(){ //do something });
    });
```

using element's class:

```
    $(function(){
        $('.yourClass').on('click',function(){ //do something });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I had another click event for the same button defined in a different js file. As soon as I deleted that function it started to work. Thanks all